# mysql get ranking position grouped with joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, the first is players

```
---------------------------------------------
| player_id | player_score | player_game_id |
---------------------------------------------
| 1         | 274          | 1              |
---------------------------------------------
| 2         | 281          | 1              |
---------------------------------------------
| 3         | 156          | 2              |
---------------------------------------------
| 4         | 199          | 2              |
---------------------------------------------
| 5         | 120          | 2              |
---------------------------------------------
```

And another table for games

```
-----------------------
| game_id | game_name |
-----------------------
| 1       | gameone   |
-----------------------
| 2       | gametwo   |
-----------------------
```

I would like to have this result

```
----------------------------------------------------
| player_id | player_score | player_rank | game_id |
----------------------------------------------------
| 2         | 281          | 1           | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 274          | 2           | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 4         | 199          | 1           | 2       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 3         | 156          | 2           | 2       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 5         | 120          | 3           | 2       |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Have anyone idea how to achieve this in mysql?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `rank()` or `row_number()`:

```
select p.*,
       rank() over (partition by player_game_id order by player_score desc) as rank
from players
order by player_game_id, player_score desc;
```

If two players have the same score, then `rank()` gives them the same ranking.  `row_number()` will arbitrarily assign them adjacent rankings.

The above works on MySQL 8+.  In earlier versions you have two options -- subqueries and variables.  Here is an example using a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from players p2
        where p2.player_game_id = p.player_game_id and
              p2.player_score > p.player_score
       ) as ranking
from players
order by player_game_id, player_score desc;
```

This is not as efficient as `rank()`.  But with an index on `players(player_game_id, player_score)` and not too many players per game, then this should have reasonable performance.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, it gives me a sintax error near (partition by player_game_id order by player_score desc) as rank

Comment: @geggiamarti . . . What version of MySQL are you using?  This works on 8+.

Comment: Oh, in fact my mysql version is 5.6