# Ranking position without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have an issue with a query,
this is my old question that was previously solved
[mysql get ranking position grouped with joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920026/mysql-get-ranking-position-grouped-with-joined-table)

The problem is that when two players have the same score, the query returns the same ranking position, like 1-1-2-3 ecc. How can I fix this?
In the player's table there are also `player_tickets` (that is the number of game played) and `player_date` that is a timestamp.

I thought to get my ranking on base of `player_score` first, `player_tickets` then, and finally `player_date`

This is my older query

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT 1 + Count(*) 
        FROM   players p2 
        WHERE  p2.`player_game` = p.`player_game` 
               AND p2.player_score > p.player_score  
               AND p2.player_status = 0) AS ranking 
FROM   players p 
ORDER  BY `player_game`, 
          player_score DESC
```

Comment: Add those columns to your `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried, but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the ranking criteria to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *, 
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
    FROM   players p2 
    WHERE  p2.player_game = p.player_game 
    AND
    (
      (p2.player_score > p.player_score) OR
      (p2.player_score = p.player_score AND p2.player_tickets > p.player_tickets) OR
      (p2.player_score = p.player_score AND p2.player_tickets = p.player_tickets AND p2.player_date > p.player_date) OR
      (p2.player_score = p.player_score AND p2.player_tickets = p.player_tickets AND p2.player_date = p.player_date AND p2.player_id > p.player_id)
    )
  ) AS ranking 
FROM players p 
ORDER BY player_game, player_score DESC;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply add more columns to the `order by` of the window function:

```
rank() over (
    partition by player_game_id 
    order by player_score desc, player_tickets desc, player_date
) as rank
```

If you really want to avoid having the same rank twice, you can also use `row_number()`, which guarantees this - when there are ties, `row_number()` affects distinct numbers (whose order is hence undefined).

Comment: Yes, I would like to use this method, but my mysql version is lower then 8, and I cannot update because I use an hosting service

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional comparisons in the subquery.  Or more easily, use variables:

```
select p.*,
       @rn := if(@g = player_game, @rn + 1,
                 if(@g := player_game, 1, 1)
                ) as ranking
from (select p.*
      from players p
      order by player_game, player_score desc, player_tickets desc, player_date desc
     ) p cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @g := 0) as seqnum;
```

In newer versions, you would just use `row_number()` if you don't want ties.

Comment: This works, but in my original question I have to divide my rows by games... do you know how can I do? Thank you very much

Comment: @geggiamarti . . . I see that.

Comment: Thank you, it seems correct, but results with duplicates... I'm being crazy

Comment: @geggiamarti . . .  There should be the same rows in the result set that are in your original data.

Comment: All rows have ranking 1

Comment: The numbers should increment for each `player_game`.  I don't see how that could be.

Comment: Yes, in fact it seems correct, I don't know why it returns only 1 positions

Comment: @geggiamarti . . . Is `player_game` an integer or string?

Comment: It is an integer, related to an autoincrement id of games table

Comment: Thank you, I will use this if the Thorsten's answer will results too slow, thanks again